# Why does generating EUV frequency combs require femtosecond enhanced cavities?

Tags: laser, non-linear-optics, laser-interaction

When generating extreme UV (EUV) frequency combs using high-order harmonic generation, why does the harmonic generation step need to be inside a femtosecond enhanced cavity for the comb to work?

More generally, I don't quite understand the concept of frequency combs, and what it takes for a light source to be a frequency comb. So: why must EUV combs be generated in such cavities? If the EUV is generated directly from a phase-locked laser (not in a cavity), would it still be an EUV comb?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 4):

In response to the questions which you included in a comment above. There were lots of questions there, and it's usually best to try and formulate them into a single, more concise question, or to ask them separately. I would have included this as a comment rather than an answer, but it is longer than the character limit.

1) Whilst I don't usually like to reference wikipedia*, the article on frequency combs is a good introduction to what frequency combs are, so [here it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_comb) (read the whole thing, there's an applications bit at the bottom).

"A frequency comb is a spectrum consisting of a series of discrete, equally spaced elements" according to the wiki page, and that's about as broad a definition as you can have. They arise whenever you have a regular, amplitude modulated signal in the time domain, e.g., from pulsed lasers (associated mainly with modelocking). If the laser pulses are emitted once every roundtrip of the laser cavity, and the roundtrip takes $12.5$ ns, then the frequency comb produced will have a frequency spacing of $1/(12.5\rm{ ns}) = 80$ MHz (in this case, the frequency comb spacing is equal to the repetition rate of the laser, and is formed of the standing modes permitted by the cavity). The optical frequency comb will be made up of frequencies separated by $80$ MHz, and will have an amplitude envelope given by that of a single pulse. If the pulsed output of the laser is incident on a photodiode which is then attached to an electrical spectrum analyser, then the modes of the frequency comb can be seen, and will stretch from the $0^{\rm{th}}$ order, with $80$ MHz spacing, up to the limit of the electrical response of the photodiode/electrical spectrum analyser.

I find it best to think of optical diffraction and Fourier transforms when thinking about optical combs in the time and frequency domains like this (the maths is the same and the physics very similar, in my opinion). Think of Young's double slits: Wide slit spacing implies closely spaced diffraction fringes, and vice versa.

Another example of when they arise is during high-harmonic generation when driven by pulses with durations longer than a single optical cycle (denoted $\tau$)**. In this case, EUV can be generated every half-cycle of the laser, giving a frequency spacing of $2/\tau$, (so producing a frequency comb peak at every odd harmonic of the driving field). So, if the frequency of your driving laser is $300$ THz, the frequency spacing will be $600$ THz. Harmonic numbers [around the $5000$ mark](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/336/6086/1287) have been generated using this technique, which allows for frequency conversion from an available (pulsed) laser wavelength into the EUV, where traditional lasers are not available.

2) Enhancement cavities are sometimes used to generate EUV for many reasons. I'll only include a few for brevity:

- They allow for the coherent addition of many driving pulses, meaning that low energy, high repetition rate laser sources can be used to generate EUV rather than low repetition rate, high energy sources. This *can* give you more EUV flux, although coupling the EUV from the cavity can be difficult.
- Generating EUV in an enhancement cavity can mean that EUV bursts can be emitted at MHz repetition rates, where (except for in a few laser systems) the repetition rate is generally restricted to a few tens of kHz.

It is important to note that it is the driving pulse which is circulated and coherently added with each roundtrip of the enhancement cavity, not the EUV. The EUV is generated within the enhancement cavity by the enhanced circulated driving pulse, but is switched out of the cavity after being generated.

The second point in the list above is an attractive one. If you have a given amount of EUV power, reducing the modes increases the amount of power *per mode*, thus giving a higher signal-to-noise ratio for any frequency comb measurements you would like to make. Also, using the enhancement cavity gives the PHz EUV frequency comb a MHz modulation, which is then used as a more useful frequency reference (see comments below).

EUV isn't always generated using enhancement cavities. There are other methods of generating it using high-harmonic generation, and other means such as x-ray free electron lasers and synchrotrons. The latter two are generally national facilities and beam time is scarce and very expensive, so high-harmonic generation has seen a lot of development recently to increase availability of coherent EUV radiation.

3) If by "phased locked lase[r]" you mean modelocked laser, then yes, that would be an EUV frequency comb. However, EUV is ionizing radiation and is therefore absorbed by pretty much everything, meaning that 'traditional' lasers aren't available for this frequency band. As such, a modelocked EUV laser is hypothetical.

*I think it's great, but I've been told that it isn't a "viable" academic source so many times...

** In the single atom model only. The plasma produced during the HHG process can cause the harmonic spacing to increase which, while maintaining the comb structure, means that it can no longer be used as a measurement reference.

Comment: Excellent answer!  I've got a few minor comments, though. No one in the field really describes standard HHG as a frequency comb, even if by a strict definition it can be seen as one. This is partly because the spacing is too big to be useful (a few PHz instead of MHz), but it's also not a good metrological standard. As an example, the ionization fraction can cause the driver to blueshift by a few percent, so by harmonic 100 you've slipped a few harmonic orders, and the harmonic comb is useless as a spectrometer.

Comment: The term EUV comb is reserved for HHG in enhancement cavities because there the MHz lines of the driver age coherently copied and unconverted into the harmonics, so each HHG harmonic is itself made up of a MHz comb, and that one doesn't slip, so it is metrologically useful.

Comment: The HHG record, btw, stands at order 5000, cf T Popmintchev et al., http://science.sciencemag.org/content/336/6086/1287 . There they couldn't resolve each harmonic line (the driver is at 3.9 microns or so, and they wanted a wide spectral range at the expense of resolution) but there is every reason to expect that the spectrum is discrete if you look.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input! Very useful comments. When writing the paragraph about EUV frequency combs I had the single atom model in mind, which obviously neglects the 'macroscopic' effects which cause harmonics to shift or drop out. In this case, 'comb' is arguably still applicable (though unorthodox). This isn't at all obvious from what I've written, so I'll edit it accordingly. I hadn't realised that "comb" was specific to HHG in enhancement cavities, but makes perfect sense, so thanks for that.

Comment: Somehow, I had forgotten about the Popmintchev paper! I was aware that it was way higher than order 100, but didn't want to overshoot...

Comment: Yeah, that 5000 sounds really outlandish, but it is actually real.

Comment: The restriction of EUV comb to just cavity HHG is just a convention, though, and by any objective definition the harmonic plateau is definitely a comb - just not very useful in that specific regard. The literature and the community do have their conventions, though, and it does part to play by those lines unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm sold on your edits, on the other hand. The plasma blueshifting does preserve the comb; what it does is increase the comb spacing, which means that you cannot use the comb as a spectrometer as you usually wild like to.

Comment: Similarly, doing the HHG in a cavity does not remove or replace the PHz comb. Instead, it adds structure: you get a PHz comb, each of whose 'teeth' is *itself* a MHz comb.

Comment: I'm sold on the edits now. Would upvote again if I could. In any case, welcome to the site! It's nice to have someone else from ultrafastsy stuff.

Comment: Cheers! There aren't too many on here that I've come across so far. I'm more familiar with nonlinear fibre optics and CPA, really, so i may be on other people's turf here! Thanks again for your input.

Comment: Oh, final comment - the 'enhancement' in femtosecond enhancement cavities is actually enhancement of the fs IR driver, not the XUV. You don't really get particularly high XUV flux (partly because coupling out is a problem), but because you don't throw away the IR you can have HHG-inducing intensities with a much smaller pulse energy on your IR source, and that's what lets you crank up the repetition rate into regimes that are useful for frequency combs.

Comment: Ok, that is what I meant, but will make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer and discussion by user113857 and Emilio Pisanty are excellent. But, I wanted to present a more concise answer to the title question:

The generation of an EUV frequency comb does not *require* an enhancement cavity. However, because frequency combs typically operate with 20+ MHz repetition rates and high-harmonic generation requires high peak intensities (typically >$10^{13} \mathrm{watts/cm^2}$), an enhancement cavity allows for efficient high-harmonic generation with reasonable (sub-kilowatt) average powers from the laser system.

While I couldn't find an example where a true optical frequency comb (pulsed laser with carrier-envelope-offset and repetition-rate stabilization) was generated in the EUV in a single-pass geometry, [this 2011 Optics Letter](https://www.osapublishing.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-36-17-3428#Abstract) demonstrates single-pass generation of HHG up to the 15th harmonic using a 20 MHz laser. This result demonstrates that (a) it's not completely necessary to use an enhancement cavity to generate an EUV comb but (b) the achievable photon energies for 20+ MHz HHG are much higher when an enhancement cavity is used to increase the peak intensity.